# How does ant tasks works internally?

Tags: scripting, ant, task, internals

I need to know how each ant tasks works internally.

I know that the replaceregexp task matches a particular string with another. But i need to know how this happens internally. Not for this task alone. I need to know about all the ant tasks avaiable...

Can you please suggest some links for it? Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to download the source code and look for yourself:

http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi